# Xsession: unable to launch "true" X session --- "true" not found; falling back to default session

Tags: xorg, 22.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (low latency) and am using Gnome on Xorg. When I launch Guayadeque music player, I get the message in the title of my question in a little dialog that pops up:

[image: Dialog showing the message in my question's title]

This is new behavior to me (as compared with 20.04, 19.10, etc.). Does it indicate that I need to configure something in my X11 system, or… ?

Some details:

```
 % uname -a                   
 Linux MyComputer 5.15.0-41-lowlatency #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 22 15:40:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 % lsb_release -a 
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
 Release:        22.04
 Codename:       jammy
```

From a comment, when I log in, I can select one of the four choices here:

- Gnome
- Gnome on Xorg
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu on Xorg

The behavior I describe at the top of my question also occurs when I select Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: ARE you running Xorg? Ubuntu 22.04 runs in Wayland by default.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I **am** running Gnome on Xorg as far as I know (at least, I **assume** that's what clicking the gear widget in the lower right of the screen and selecting "Gnome on Xorg" does). Please educate me if I am in error about this.

Comment: Odd, with a standard kernel the choices are "ubuntu" and "ubuntu on xorg" (or "ubuntu on wayland" if the default is xorg).  What is the output of uname -a and lsb_release -a ?  Maybe some other test got messed up too by the different kernel.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you! See my edit. (I have installed a whole bunch of stuff—that's a metric whole bunch, mind you, not imperial—so it is conceivable some of it may have begreebled something.)

Answer (score 3):

Bump, this is happening to me as well, also Gnome on Xorg.

The suggested fix from here seems to help (at least the message is gone):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1983185

Will see if the future upgrades break it again.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that attempted fix, but the problem persists.

Comment: This was the change that worked on my setup: https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/-/merge_requests/16/diffs